# Twig variables wont work in an include js file?

Tags: templating, variable, jquery

Im trying to put my  code in a included theme.js file. It wont recognize my variables anymore.

Working in .rain file within the html code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var uspicon1 = "{{ theme.usp_1_icon }}";
    var uspicon2 = "{{ theme.usp_2_icon }}";
    var uspicon3 = "{{ theme.usp_3_icon }}";
    var uspicon4 = "{{ theme.usp_4_icon }}";
    jQuery('.icon1').addClass(uspicon1);
    jQuery('.icon2').addClass(uspicon2);  
    jQuery('.icon3').addClass(uspicon3);  
    jQuery('.icon4').addClass(uspicon4); 
  });
</script>
```

Not working with an include .js file:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var uspicon1 = "{{ theme.usp_1_icon }}";
    var uspicon2 = "{{ theme.usp_2_icon }}";
    var uspicon3 = "{{ theme.usp_3_icon }}";
    var uspicon4 = "{{ theme.usp_4_icon }}";
    jQuery('.icon1').addClass(uspicon1);
    jQuery('.icon2').addClass(uspicon2);  
    jQuery('.icon3').addClass(uspicon3);  
    jQuery('.icon4').addClass(uspicon4); 
  });
```

Practicly the same without the script tags. I tested a console.log() and it works fine. I'm guessing it wont recognize my {{ variables }} in .js file.

Anybody know what the syntax is?

Answer (score 4):

There is no "syntax" for it since you don't parse these files with PHP.
You'll have to declare your variables inside a twig file

## First Approach

#### Twig

```
<script>
    var myVariable = {{ theme|json_encode|raw }}
</script>
```

#### Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var uspicon1 = myVariable.usp_1_icon;
    var uspicon2 = myVariable.usp_2_icon;
    var uspicon3 = myVariable.usp_3_icon;
    var uspicon4 = myVariable.usp_4_icon;
    jQuery('.icon1').addClass(uspicon1);
    jQuery('.icon2').addClass(uspicon2);  
    jQuery('.icon3').addClass(uspicon3);  
    jQuery('.icon4').addClass(uspicon4); 
});
```

## Second Approach

Or you move your Javascript inside a Twig file

```
{% js %}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var uspicon1 = "{{ theme.usp_1_icon }}";
    var uspicon2 = "{{ theme.usp_2_icon }}";
    var uspicon3 = "{{ theme.usp_3_icon }}";
    var uspicon4 = "{{ theme.usp_4_icon }}";
    jQuery('.icon1').addClass(uspicon1);
    jQuery('.icon2').addClass(uspicon2);
    jQuery('.icon3').addClass(uspicon3);
    jQuery('.icon4').addClass(uspicon4);
});
{% endjs %}
```

You can as well attach the attributes in your html - that makes it much easier

## Third Approach

#### Twig

```
<div class="icon4" data-icon="{{theme.usp_4_icon}}"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
var element = jQuery('.icon4')
element.addClass(element.data('class'));
```